# Install a gem from a bundler package on new machine without bundler

Tags: ruby, centos, rubygems, bundler

I have a cached gem in a repository. The gem was saved using the `bundle package --all` command.

On a newly-built machine (centos), which doesn't have Bundler installed, but does have a copy of this repo, I want to avoid connecting to the internet and install the gem from this local copy.

Is it possible to install this gem without installing bundler ?

Comment: Is `gem install gem_name -v '1.2.3'` not suitable for your purposes? That does assume you want a standard published version (not version pulled from github and now cached in your repo) . . .

Comment: gem install connects to the internet. I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the local path to the gem instead of its name:

```
gem install ./vendor/cache/gem-name.gem
```